# PowerPoint Presenter View - Reset timer after every slide change

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to reset the timer or add an additional timer which resets itself whenever the slide changes when presenting in Presenter View? Like when I move from slide 1 to slide 2, timer resets. Then again when move from slide 2 to slide 3, timer resets. This way I know how much time I have spent on individual side. I am using Mac.

[image]

Comment: What kind of slide changes?

Comment: like when I move from slide 1 to slide 2, timer should reset. Then again when I move from slide 2 to slide 3, timer resets. This way I can see how much time I have spent on an individual slide

Comment: There are related plugins on the Internet that can implement this function.